# What to add in bean for controller accessing service in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, controller

I am making a spring boot application and made some controllers,services and Repository for DB operations.But my controller is not working even when I am defining the Controller beans.

Below is my code:
`ClientController`:

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/clients")
public class ClientController {

    /** The logger. */
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);
    
    @LazyAutowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @GetMapping(value = {"/",""})
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getClients() {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap = clientService.getClients();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/",""})
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> postClient(@Valid @RequestBody ClientModel client) {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap = clientService.addClient(client);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMap, HttpStatus.OK);
}}
```

Now here's my service:
`ClientService`

```
@Service
public class ClientService {

    @LazyAutowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public Map<String, Object> getClients() {
        List<ClientModel> clients = clientRepository.findAll();
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap.put("clients", clients);
        return responseMap;
    }}
```

Here's my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientModel, String> {
    ClientModel findByClientName(String clientName);
}
```

Here's my `Bean` config file:
All the controllers are working but client controller is not working.

```
<bean id="versionController" class="com.api.version.VersionController">
    <property name="authMode" value="passthru" />
</bean>
   
<bean id="clientController" class="com.api.clients.ClientController">
</bean>
```

In the above config,Version Controller is working but ClientController is not working.
Is there anything I need to add in Bean property?
My component scan path:

```
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.api, com.documents, com..mdm">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

Any Help?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that your controller isn't working? Does it return 404 error when you're trying to access `GET /api/clients/` or `POST /api/clients/`?

Comment: I am getting a 404 error for all the routes in controller.

Comment: If you're using Actuator, you can check whether your controller was registered by calling `/actuator/mappings` endpoint. If it's not registered, you should check your component scan path.

Comment: I added my component scan in the question,Can you check once?

Comment: Is your `ClientController` placed in the correct package? How do you start your application?

Comment: yes,its in the correct package. I start it using tomcat

Comment: I think i need to add some properties in bean for controller,Is it the case?

Comment: In your question, you said that you're using Spring Boot. Usually Spring Boot applications being started by `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on the main class. Also, in your question you're referring to a XML configuration that should be imported with `@ImportResource` annotation on your main class as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-xml-beans. So I was asking for your main class definition for Spring Boot application.

Comment: what is LazyAutowired?